# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unknown column 'm.MenusMenuId' in 'field list'' in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

Anyone can help me to solve this problem please.

I get a MySql unknown column error, the error is m.MenusMenuId but inside MySql my menu id is MenuId. MenuId how can become m.MenusMenuId? Anyone can explain to me please. Here my code below.

Menus.cs

```
public class Menus
{
    [Key]
    public int MenuId { set; get; }
    public string MenuName { set; get; }
    public int? ParentId { set; get; }
    public int ActiveNo { set; get; }
    public List<Menus> MenuList { set; get; } = new List<Menus>();
}
```

Context.cs

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Menus> menus { set; get; }
}
```

MenusController.cs

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MenusController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly Context _context;

    public MenusController(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;

        if (_context.menus.Count() == 0)
        {
            _context.menus.Add(new Menus { MenuId = 1, MenuName = "VEHICLE TRADING", ParentId = null, ActiveNo = 1 });
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<Menus>> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.menus.ToList();
    }
}
```

MySql Query

```
CREATE TABLE Menus(
    MenuId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    MenuName VARCHAR(250),
    ParentId INT,
    ActiveNo INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (MenuId)
);
```

Comment: Search your entire solution for "MenusMenuId" to see where it's being used.

Comment: I have no any MenusMenuId

Comment: It must be somewhere in your solution. Are you using Entity Framework? It could be in one of the auto-generated files.

Comment: Im using EntityFrameworkCore, i have only the int MenuId in the Menus class, but when i run, it become MenusMenuId.

Comment: From any file, press Ctrl+F, change the drop-down to "Entire Solution" and search for "MenusMenuId". It has to be there somewhere.

Comment: I found it, the problem is inside my Menus.cs i got a MenuList there.

Comment: But if dont have the MenuList, i cant put the children inside MenuList. So that means i cant create a dynamic menu properly also